# How to run a service on vm when its bootstapped from cloud init

Tags: service, cloud-init

I am trying to run zabbix agent when my vm comes up

my cloudinit.txt (part of it) loks like this :-

```
runcmd:
 - [ ls, -l, / ]
 - [ ls, -l, /usr ] 
 - [ sudo service zabbix-agent restart ]
```

and i get

```
cloud-init[1025]: lrwxrwxrwx.   1 root root    10 Dec  1 13:05 tmp -> ../var/tmp
cloud-init[1025]: /var/lib/cloud/instance/scripts/runcmd: line 4: sudo service zabbix-agent restart: command not found
cloud-init[1025]: 2015-03-01 07:04:14,307 - util.py[WARNING]: Failed running /var/lib/cloud/instance/scripts/runcmd [127]
cloud-init[1025]: 2015-03-01 07:04:14,316 - cc_scripts_user.py[WARNING]: Failed to run module scripts-user (scripts in /var/lib/cloud/instance/scripts)
cloud-init[1025]: 2015-03-01 07:04:14,316 - util.py[WARNING]: Running scripts-user (<module 'cloudinit.config.cc_scripts_user' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cloudinit/config/cc_scripts_user.pyc'>) failed
```

most of the commands work ( I am able to list the directory) 
but the service does not start and i get this in logs:-

```
sudo service zabbix-agent restart: command not found
```

If I log into ,y vm ..i am able to start it using the same command

Answer (score 0):

Since I was on centos, I ended up using:

```
systemctl enabled zabbix-agent.service
```